# How to manage users using REST API at Laravel Jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I'm making an application with Laravel8/Jetstream backend and Vue2 FrontEnd.

I think Jetstream's documentation is not so clear, in opponent to Laravel's documentation and Laracasts by  JEFFREY WAY, which are great and usable.
But customizing this new Auth feature are less documented IMHO.

I would like to make a frontend page for managing users by admin and a profile manager for every user to edit their own data with password change function - and use a controller to use the Jetstreams' (and Fortify) services.

I didn't found any help or best practice in which way should I go.

Please help me to put me on the right way.

Comment: Fortify already provided you all the logic. You may inspect your routes to understand what auth routes fortify gives you. Your frontend can than simply hook up to those routes.

Comment: I've found those routes and Controllers. 
I made an own controller to handle the request from my frontend, I don't want to use separate Save button for Profile Information and Password (or should I? Maybe more cleaner and easier...)

But unfortunatelly I don't know how to call those Controllers from My controller... :(

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Finally I woke up this morning enlighted what did your comment mean... I just simply router my API to "user/profile-information" and it worked (after I enabled Jetstream's API feature and insert 'user/*' into my cors config). 
Thank you. 
(IMHO that should be clarified in the documentation.)
However it works for the current user only. How should I manage other users?

Comment: You'd need to create a custom route and custom controller logic to retrieve user information, much like you'd do that with any other model. For example, your route could be `users/{id}/profile-information`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Maarteen pointed out, I had to use the routes provided by Jetstream:

To update the current user's profile information with API support turned on, a PUT request must be called to the `user/profile-information` route.

To change his/her password, a PUT request must be called to the `user/password` route.
Here, the `App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword` action is called, which uses the password validation rules provided by the `App\Actions\Fortify\PasswordValidationRules` class.

To manage users by an administrator I had to create a new controller with custom actions, but for example, for the new user creation logic I used the CreatesNewUsers class to get the input and it uses the `App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser`class, which can be customized.